# I have come across this code snippet as shown below. Can anyone suggest what is the meaning of a in scanf function

Tags: c

Can anyone suggest what is the meaning of `a` in the following call to `scanf`?

```
scanf("%d a %f",&i,&f)
```

Comment: it's an 'a' expected in the input ......

Comment: @MitchWheat which a you are talking about. in actual code its not scanning the f and displaying the default value of f.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Characters preceded by a '%' in a call to [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) represent variables.

For instance `%d` represents an integer variable whereas `%f` represents a floating-point variable.

Characters which are not preceded by a `%` (or a `\`, which indicates an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)) are taken literally, so, in your case, the scanf string `"%d a %f"` would match `"233 a 4.5"` but would not match `"233 b 4.5"`.

(To be more accurate, a whitespace character matches any contiguous sequence of whitespace characters.)

Comment: You're welcome, @Amit. If this answer was helpful, you can vote it up by clicking the up arrow next to the answer. If this answer was the best answer you got you can make it the "Accepted Answer" by clicking the outline of the checkbox next to it.

Comment: Here my reputation is low so i cnt vote yet.. bt anyways thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d a %f",&i,&f)
```

Means you have to type in data , in this format 25 a 33.3

Then when you print it using

```
printf("i=%d f=%f",i,f);
```

and then you get the output as

```
i = 25 , f = 33.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the value of the variable `f` because of the `&` in the line `scanf("%d a %f",&i,&f)`

The `&` means you are getting the address of the variable `f` in the memory. You should remove the  '`&`'s to get the actual value of the variables.

And for the a:

- Non-whitespace character, except format specifier (%): Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character) causes the function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of format. If the character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving subsequent characters of the stream unread.

Which means you are formatting the input as so:

1. type in a decimal integer(%d)
2. then a space
3. then the character 'a'
4. another space
5. then the floating point number(%f).

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: I find your sentence regarding the `&` very confusing. The OP most certainly does not want to remove the `&` if they are trying to use `scanf`.